# Enable "It's now safe to turn off PC" in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I have an ACPI PC but the power button is in a concealed box so I have to screw it open to press it. I have the "Restore on powerloss" enabled so it would power on once it receives power, so the PC can be turned on/off using the power strip. How do I turn on the message? If it's not possible, how do I  make the restore on powerloss work even when Windows turns the H/W off?

Comment: What if you let Windows turn the hardware off, you turn the power strip off, wait 10 s an turn in on again? I've seen BIOSes where "restore on power loss" could be configured as "always" or "if previously on". With "always" the hardware starts when the electricity returns, regardless if it was shut down abruptly or nicely via ACPI.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski IT only turns on if the power was cut while running. If Windows turns the H/W off it doesn;t work.

Comment: [This article](https://windowsreport.com/safe-turn-off-computer/), at least for W10 Pro. I won't post an answer because I don't use Windows and I cannot test/confirm this. If anyone wants to base their answer on the linked method, go ahead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shutdown Windows 10 without power off computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1599332/shutdown-windows-10-without-power-off-computer)

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  This message only appears when ACPI is not enabled or supported in the UEFI/BIOS.  However, starting with Windows Vista (it might actually be Windows 7), ACPI is required and Windows won't install or boot if ACPI is not enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's the same as the GameCube kill screen, you know, the screen where Mario has no eyes in one part, and another that says it is malfunctioning? That creeps me out,but i read this article by a kid saying one guy's computer (the OS was Windows NT Beta 2) showed the same screen, except it showed the "Restart" option. I think it's kinda like a game over screen, except it says "It's now safe to power off your PC." but with blood on the text and skulls everywhere.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).